# Oracle: Convert string to double

Tags: sql, vb.net, oracle

This is my query for a database pull:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
TEMPLATE_GROUP_PROPERTIES.PROPERTYTYPE,
PROPERTY.PROPERTYVAL

FROM
TEMPLATE_GROUP_PROPERTIES

LEFT OUTER JOIN PROPERTY_DATA
ON (TEMPLATE_GROUP_PROPERTIES.PROPERTYGROUPID = PROPERTYDATA.PROPERTYGROUPID)

WHERE
PROPERTY.PROPERTYVAL = :propValue
```

Whoever created the database made the `Property.Propertyval` column a column defined as a string when it is represented as scientific notation numbers (4.0E-3, 2.0E2, etc). I need to convert either the string to a double or the double to a string whatever way would work and I don't know how. I have tried messing around with the `TO_NUMBER()` function and have found nothing of help so far.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you really know that the string is a valid number, then use `cast()`:

```
WHERE cast(property.propertyval as float) = :propValue
```

Some cautions.

First, the use of the function will prevent the query from using an index on `propertyval`.  You can always create a functional index if you need an index.

Second, comparisons of floating point values can be problematic when the values are very close.  You might consider:

```
WHERE abs(cast(property.propertyval as float) - :propValue) < 0.001
```

Or some other threshold value.

Comment: @bbesase . . . In the second case, instead of looking for an exact match, you are looking for two values that are very close together (less than the threshold number).  This is because two floats could look the same, but differ on the very last bit and be different.